# Elementary Shell Script For Unix

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

I need help with writing this shell script. Could someone please help me. Thanks.

Write a shell script my_echo that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments and prints them, one per line, adding text "(this is an integer)" after each argument, which is an integer.

Comment: Sounds like a homework

Answer (score -2):

use this

save this to my_echo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
a=$1
b=$2
c=$3
text=10
a=$[$a + $text]
b=$[$b + $text]
c=$[$c + $text]
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
echo "$c"
```

then chmod 777 my_echo.sh

then run ./my_echo.sh 2 4 6

Comment: No No no NO! chmod 777 is **NEVER** acceptable.

Comment: Apart from that, this doesn't do what the OP needs

Comment: I did not even check that after I saw the failed #, the direct path to a potential bash location and the code which seemed very inflexible. I would expect something with shift registers.

Comment: Then give chmod u+x because you only run the program. Or try simply as sh my_echo.sh 2 4 6